# ASP.NET restrict application

Tags: asp.net, security, licensing, asp.net-4.5

Currently I am working on multiple projects as a third party (outsourced) where I have no control over the hosting. My application is modular enough to be changed on the fly, all that's required is slight edit in Html / CSS and it'll become a brand new site.

I do not want my proprietary codes to leak on the web without my consent.

Since I'm contracted to only work on a few particular domains, I wish to "lock" them down in the sense there won't be multiple instances of the same application running in the wild.

Domain locking comes to mind, but this will be rather restrictive as my client will no longer be able to change domain in the future.

Any other inexpensive ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having a registration server somewhere that requires various libraries in the system to register infrequently.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, if you have a remote server that each version of your app has to register with on start-up this could be a way around it.  You pass in the domain name that is running the app and test it against what is registered on your remote server.  (Though this will incur a charge, but it shouldn't be horrendous).

Comment: I shall try that. Thank you